# Access / update textbox value after creating it on runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm creating multiple textboxes at runtime. The problem is that I cannot seem to update their value individually after rendering on runtime. The textbox.text always ends up showing its initial text ("Hello") in the GUI rather than what I want to show after changing it ("World"):

```
        public Dictionary<int,TextBox> txtbx123dictionary = new Dictionary<int,TextBox>

        public void LoadParameters()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = GetParameters();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    paramtxtbx = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    txtbx123dictionary.Add(i, paramtxtbx);
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Text = "Hello"
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Name = "TextBox" + i.ToString();
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, (i * 25));
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 20);
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Visible = true;
                    panel123.Controls.Add(paramdict.ElementAt(i).Value);
                    //panel123.Add(i, paramtxtbx);
                }
            }

            public void function()
            {
                LoadParameters();
                for (int i = 0; i < txtbx123dictionary.Count(); i++)
                {
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Text = "World";
                    txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Update();
                    panel123.Update();
                }
            }
```

e.g I need to change the textbox.text to "World" but when running the code the text box keeps on showing "Hello".
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running `function()` on the UI thread?  More than likely not, which means changes to the control won't show up on the screen.

Comment: Try debugging and see if it hits the line where you are setting text to "World"

Comment: What is and where do you declare `paramdict`?

Comment: are you wanting to add the text of the object in this line `txtbx123dictionary.Add(i, paramtxtbx);` if so then you need to add `paramtxtbx.Text` also what's the real use of `for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)` doesn't look like you are adding the values from the datatable to the dictionary object.. use the debugger to see what you are doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

`txtbx123dictionary.ElementAt(i)` not the same as `txtbx123dictionary[i]`

`ElementAt(i)` is extensions method from `IEnumerable<T>`

You add `TextBox` to the dictionary by key `i` then try it get by index `i`.